# which inbuilt java class doesn't override equals and hashcode methods? why?

Tags: java

I wanted to know the use of overriding of equals and hashcode methods.
Can Anyone tell which inbuilt java class doesn't override equals and hashcode methods? why?

Comment: Look at their javadoc. If it has an equals() and a hashCode() method, then it's overriding them, and the javadoc explains why. If they don't, then it measn that their superclass implementation of equals() and hashCode() is sufficient. Reading the javadoc of Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() allows understanding what these methods are for.

Comment: And of course the `Object` class itself doesn't override any methods!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a class has no fields it makes no sense to override equals / hashCode

Comment: Do we have a built-in class with no field? I can't remember any.

Comment: @mok Most of the built-in subclasses of `Exception` don't have any fields of their own, and don't override `hashCode` or `equals`.